# Get added to cart custom field data in WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

In WooCommerce, I am setting a custom field when a product is added to cart in a cookie:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpcd_set_cookie', 1 );
function wpcd_set_cookie() {
    if(isset( $_POST[ 'idp' ] ) ) :
        $cookie_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'idp' ] );
        setcookie( 'idp', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 999), '/' ); // 86400 = 1 day            
        header("Refresh:0");            
    endif;
}
```

The cookie is correctly set, but I can't get its value in this hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ustanovka_oplaty');
function ustanovka_oplaty( $order_id) {

    $idp = isset( $_COOKIE['idp'] ) ? $_COOKIE['idp'] : 'not set';

    // this $idp = 'not set ' why?  

    add_post_meta($order_id, 'wpcf-idvopros', $idp, true);
}
```

Why?

How can I solve this issue?

---

EDIT - My form add product to cart:

```html
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="PaySumForm" method="post">

    <input type="hidden"  name="idp" id="idp" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="required requiredField " />

    <button type="contsubmit" class="payb qbutton">buy</button>

</form>
```

Comment: @pan1ka when and/or where are you posting `'idp'` value from your custom field?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec.. Lucky you're an expert on this and seemingly can help pan1ka out. I had this question for review and found similarities based on wording for it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i'm set 'idp' after user add product to cart. The correct value is recorded normally, and if you look at the cookies on the order's erase, then 'idp' is set correctly. However, inside the function, the value 'idp' is returned as "not set".

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It seems that $ _COOKIE does not work inside my hook, but I can not understand why.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You do not understand me, I have no problems with writing data to the custom order field. I do not get to transfer the value of the page ID on which the product was added to the order after a successful payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Answering the why:**
>
> It's is because a cookie is set on client side *(in customer browser)*. The `woocommerce_order_status_completed` is a backend Woocommerce process and can't access that cookie data.

Now you should **forget cookies** and use the following code:

1) Save your "idp" custom field value in the Cart item

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_product_field_in_cart', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_product_field_in_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['idp'] ) )
        $cart_item_data[ 'idp' ] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['idp']);

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

2) Save "idp" custom field value in the order metadata (temporarily):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_idvopros_as_order_meta', 10, 3 );
function save_idvopros_as_order_meta( $order_id, $data ) {
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)
        $idp = empty($cart_item['idp']) ? 'no' : $cart_item['idp'];
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_idvopros_temp', $idp, true);
}
```

3) To finish, function revisited:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ustanovka_oplaty');
function ustanovka_oplaty( $order_id) {

    $idp = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_idvopros_temp', true );
    if ( ! empty( $idp ) ) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'wpcf-idvopros', $idp );
        delete_post_meta($order_id, '_idvopros_temp' );
    }
}
```

This should work

Comment: How get this data in woocommerce_order_status_completed action hook? 
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ustanovka_oplaty');

function ustanovka_oplaty( $order_id) {

$target_product_id = 429;

  foreach ( $order_id->get_order() as $key => $value ) {
         if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $idp = $value['idp'] ;
        }
    }

it's true code?